# TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined - Fixing needed

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I made a user info command and one of the things I would like to show is the roles of the member. But for some odd reason, I am getting a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined`.

Please help me and my code is listed below for reference. Thanks!

```
case 'whois': {
  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  var user = message.mentions.users.first()            
  if(!args[1]) return message.reply('Apologies! Please specify a particular member!');

  embed.setTitle('User Information')
  embed.addField('Username', user.username)
  embed.addField('User ID', user.id)
  embed.addField('User Tag', user.tag)
  embed.addField('Roles:', user.roles.cache.map(r =>`${r}`).join(' | '))
  embed.addField('Created at:', user.createdAt)             
  embed.setColor(0x00FF93)
  embed.setThumbnail(user.avatarURL())
  embed.setFooter('Generated by Salty!')
  message.channel.send(embed);
  break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `user.roles` is undefined.

You can use a safe fallback by changing your Roles line to the following:

```
embed.addField('Roles:', user.roles ? user.roles.cache.map(r =>`${r}`).join(' | ') : '')
```

Comment: That not exactly needed, Proper `GuildMember` object will always have `roles` property.
Error in question comes from the fact that they are using `User` object instead of `GuildMember`.

Comment: Additionally, i don't think that `roles?.cache` is proper way, as there is no indication that OP uses TypeScript, and according to [node.green](https://node.green/#ES2020-features-optional-chaining-operator-----) it's not available even in Node 14.0.0 yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is because users do not have roles. only GuildMembers do. If you want to get the first mentioned member, use message.mentions.members.first(). Users represent worldwide discord users, while GuildMembers are members of specific guilds.

Comment: If you point that out, you could also explain how to fix it. Proper way to fix error in question would be to use `var member = message.mentions.members.first()` instead of `var user = message.mentions.users.first()`, of course replacing `user` with `member` below, to not get `member is not defined` errors.